# Clicking on overlapping UI elements

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have a `Fragment` that takes up half the `Activity`. Behind it, a `ListView`.
The problem is that when the user taps anywhere on the `Fragment` that overlaps with a row on the `ListView`, the row gets clicked and it's `onClick` method gets called.

A workaround was giving an `onClick` to the `LinearLayout` in the `Fragment` layout XML file, like so :

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.example.karimnseirackground="@color/material_blue_grey_950"
    android:onClick="doNothing">
```

Which I don't think is very elegant because I have to add a `doNothing` method to every `Activity` that uses this `Fragment`

If there isn't a way to stop onClicks from being called on elements BEHIND the `Fragment`, how can I still give it a null `onClick` without having a dummy method everywhere ?

Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of setting the `android:onClick` you can just set `android:clickable="true"`. This will let the `View` capture the click and not pass it to the view behind.